# How to Read/ Parse Data of Signed_Request from Registration Script in Php 5.1.6

Tags: php, facebook, registration, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to implement the Facebook registration script.

The form is getting submitted fine and the server is receiving the signed request. However, it is not able to read/parse the signed request.

I used the script recommended on the registration page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ (code below) and all I see for output is:

signed_request contents:

I have verified that the signed_Request is being received. If I pass it to: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo?signed_request=  I see data.

However on my server with the script below nothing.

The server is http NOT https and using php 5.1.6 (which doesn't have some of the JSON support) Do I need PHP SDK installed? Or the jsonwrapper? I've tried the jsonwrapper but not PHP SDK.

Any help on why the signed_request can not be read would be appreciated.

Code below from facebook

```
    <?php
    include ('jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper.php');


    define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'XXX');
    define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'XXX');

    function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if ($_REQUEST) {
  echo '<p>signed_request contents:</p>';

  $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                                   FACEBOOK_SECRET);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($response);
  echo '</pre>';

} else {
  echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}
?>
```

output is

"signed_request contents:"

If I add: 
 print_r($_REQUEST); to the script I do see the  request but can't parse it

Comment: what is the purpose of the json wrapper here?

Comment: i read somewhere php 5.1.6 can not read JSON so you need the wrapper

Comment: any version of php can read json. it is an extension. Most hosting providers have it installed or can enable with a php.ini setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the PHP SDK for this. It may make it easier to do this and various other things, but it is not necessary if you want to do the decode yourself.

Are you sure you actually have a json_decode function? I don't think it's usually part of jsonwrapper.php, so I suspect your script is crashing on that function call.  You can use the following function as a substitute, just change the call to `usr_json_decode` and include the following at the bottom of your script:

```
function usr_json_decode($json, $assoc=FALSE, $limit=512, $n=0, $state=0, $waitfor=0)
{
  $val=NULL;
  static $lang_eq = array("true" => TRUE, "false" => FALSE, "null" => NULL);
  static $str_eq = array("n"=>"\012", "r"=>"\015", "\\"=>"\\", '"'=>'"', "f"=>"\f", "b"=>"\b", "t"=>"\t", "/"=>"/");
  for (; $n<strlen($json); /*n*/)
    {
    $c=$json[$n];
    if ($state==='"')
      {
      if ($c=='\\')
        {
        $c=$json[++$n];
        if (isset($str_eq[$c]))
          $val.=$str_eq[$c];
        else if ($c=='u')
          {
          $hex=hexdec(substr($json, $n+1, 4));
          $n+=4;
          if ($hex<0x80) $val .= chr($hex);
          else if ($hex<0x800) $val.=chr(0xC0+$hex>>6).chr(0x80+$hex&63);
          else if ($hex<=0xFFFF) $val.=chr(0xE0+$hex>>12).chr(0x80+($hex>>6)&63).chr(0x80+$hex&63);
          }
        else
          $val.="\\".$c;
        }
      else if ($c=='"') $state=0;
      else $val.=$c;
      }
    else if ($waitfor && (strpos($waitfor, $c)!==false))
      return array($val, $n);
    else if ($state===']')
      {
      list($v, $n)=usr_json_decode($json, $assoc, $limit, $n, 0, ",]");
      $val[]=$v;
      if ($json[$n]=="]") return array($val, $n);
      }
    else
      {
      if (preg_match("/\s/", $c)) { }
      else if ($c=='"') $state='"';
      else if ($c=="{")
        {
        list($val, $n)=usr_json_decode($json, $assoc, $limit-1, $n+1, '}', "}");
        if ($val && $n) $val=$assoc?(array)$val:(object)$val;
        }
      else if ($c=="[")
        list($val, $n)=usr_json_decode($json, $assoc, $limit-1, $n+1, ']', "]");
      elseif (($c=="/") && ($json[$n+1]=="*"))
        ($n=strpos($json, "*/", $n+1)) or ($n=strlen($json));
      elseif (preg_match("#^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[eE]([-+]?\d+))?#", substr($json, $n), $uu))
        {
        $val = $uu[1];
        $n+=strlen($uu[0])-1;
        if (strpos($val, ".")) $val=(float)$val;
        else if ($val[0]=="0") $val=octdec($val);
        else $val=(int)$val;
        if (isset($uu[2])) $val*=pow(10, (int)$uu[2]);
        }
      else if (preg_match("#^(true|false|null)\b#", substr($json, $n), $uu))
        {
        $val=$lang_eq[$uu[1]];
        $n+=strlen($uu[1])-1;
        }
      else
        {
        return $waitfor ? array(NULL, 1<<30) : NULL;
        }
      }
    if ($n===NULL) return NULL;
    $n++;
    }
  return ($val);
}
```

BTW though, this should be very easy to track down using your error log, turning on extra debugging and adding some `echo` or `var_dump` statements as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Even with your function i still get errors. 
 Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in *** on line 95

line 95:  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {

I'm going to upgrade to php 5.2 but in the interim am stuck

Comment: Did you change the line above that to `$data = usr_json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);`? The error indicates that $data is a Class rather than an Array, and therefore whatever json_decode function you are calling is returning a Class. The one I gave definitely returns an array, so it sounds like you are getting a different json_decode function pulled in from somewhere else. Get rid of the jsonwrapper stuff and make sure you are calling usr_json_decode().

Comment: i've got it working now. I upgraded to 5.2 to get JSON working. May have worked before then because at some point in trying the proposed changes I wasn't using my own facebook key so of course the proposed changes wouldn't work. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar with the signed request coming back blank. On your application make sure you first download and inlude the php sdk from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/. Next add

```
 require_once("facebook.php");
```

to your script at the top, or to where you uploaded it to. Now in your application settings for the application, in Facebook, make sure your url to the application has the www in it or not. For example: In the application you have it pointing to example.com/index.php?tab=test but when you put it in the browser it always comes up www,example.com/index.php?tab=test. Not including the www can mess it up.

### EDIT - WORKED FOR ME

```
    <?php
    #error_reporting(E_ALL);

        include ('{{PATH TO facebook.php}}');


        $appapikey = 'xxxx';
        $appsecret = 'xxxx';
        $facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

    function parsePageSignedRequest() {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
          $encoded_sig = null;
          $payload = null;
          list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
          $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
          $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
          return $data;
        }
        return false;
      }
      function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
          list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

          // decode the data
          $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
          $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

          if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
            error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
            return null;
          }

          // check sig
          $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
          if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
            return null;
          }

          return $data;
        }
        function base64_url_decode($input) {
          return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
        }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      echo '<p>signed_request contents:</p>';

      $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                                       $appsecret);
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($response);
      echo '</pre>';

    } else {
      echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
    }
    ?> 
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                 client_id=134219456661289&
                 redirect_uri={{YOUR SITE URL ENCODED}}&fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
            scrolling="auto"
            frameborder="no"
            style="border:none"
            allowTransparency="true"
            width="100%"
            height="330">
    </iframe>

      function getDefinedVars($varList, $excludeList)
      {
          $temp1 = array_values(array_diff(array_keys($varList), $excludeList));
          $temp2 = array();
          while (list($key, $value) = each($temp1)) {
              global $$value;
              $temp2[$value] = $$value;
          }
          return $temp2;
      }
```

To view All SYSTEM Variables (except globals/files/cookies/post/get) to make sure Signed Request is passed you can use this snippet of code

```
      /**
       * @desc   holds the variable that are to be excluded from the list.
       *         Add or drop new elements as per your preference.
       * @var    array
       */
      $excludeList = array('GLOBALS', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_POST', '_GET', 'excludeList');

      //some dummy variables; add your own or include a file.
      $firstName = 'kailash';
      $lastName = 'Badu';
      $test = array('Pratistha', 'sanu', 'fuchhi');

      //get all variables defined in current scope
      $varList = get_defined_vars();

      //Time to call the function
      print "<pre>";
      print_r(getDefinedVars($varList, $excludeList));
      print "</pre>";
```

Comment: I'm still getting problems. Turning on error_reporting has helped :)
I get this error:   cannot use object of type stdClass as array in *** on line 21

line 21:  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {