# Can't parse signed_request for Facebook registration form

Tags: facebook

I have visited these answers but to no avail. [How to Read/ Parse Data of Signed_Request from Registration Script in Php 5.1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631518/how-to-read-parse-data-of-signed-request-from-registration-script-in-php-5-1-6)

I am also using the same code as in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/.

What's wrong with the code? if I use print_r($_REQUEST['signed_request']) I can see the signed_request but the $response variable returns null even I can't see nothing after the line: signed_request contents: in the browser.

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'xxxx');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if ($_REQUEST) {
  echo '<p>signed_request contents:</p>';
  $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],FACEBOOK_SECRET);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($response);
  echo '</pre>';
} else {
  echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

I suspect you'll find that json_decode is not available in your version of PHP, in which case you'll have to either add it or use your own equivalent function.

Comment: Thanks, Floyd. I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash_hmac() in /home/httpd/www/xx/xxx/redirect.php on line 21

Comment: You are apparently using an older version of PHP that does not have the hash extension installed.  You will either need to install that extension, or find some code for a user-defined hash_hmac function that you can use in place of the system one.